# i am getting time out error for the code mentioned . need help to optimise the nested loop

Tags: java, optimization

I am getting TIME OUT error at runtime when the following nested loop is used on large arrays.

I have tried nested for loop and nested for each. While both have their time complexity same. Hence, it doesn't optimize the code.

Complete the maxXor function below.

```
static int[] maxXor(int[] arr, int[] queries) {     
    int[] result = new int[queries.length];

    int max ;
    //Finding the maximum of each query with array(arr) .
    for(int i=0;i<queries.length;i++)
    {   
        max = 0;
        for(int j=0;j<arr.length;j++)
        {
           if((queries[i] ^ arr[j]) > max)
           max = queries[i] ^ arr[j];
        }

      result[i] = max;   
    } 

    return result;
```

expected result = maximum result array for each queries.

actual result = TIME OUT error

Comment: You're most probably supposed to find a smarter algorithm, i.e., something avoiding the two nested loops. As both `arr` and `queries` can be as big as `1e9` (assuming it's a hackerrank problem), there's no hope for your `1e18` steps to finish in time.

Answer (score 0):

Timeout error sounds strange, what is the cardinality of the arrays?

Can it be due to a lack of memory problem?

Comment: Cardinality lies within 1000 while elements of both queries array and arr array is of long type.

Comment: No memory issue

Answer (score 0):

Try with this version of your function:

```
static int[] maxXor(int[] arr, int[] queries) {
    int[] result = new int[queries.length];

    //Finding the maximum of each query with array(arr) .
    for (int i = 0; i < queries.length; i++) {
        result[i] = 0;

        for (int j : arr) {
            int or = queries[i] ^ j;
            result[i] = or > result[i] ? or : result[i];
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: It is resulting to the same error. Infact, more number of test cases are being failed in this case.

Comment: Original problem link https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/maximum-xor/problem?h_r=internal-search.